# How to select next element?

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors, hide, onchange, show

I'm working on tags list. There are maximum of five input tags. First two are shown by default... done! When user types something in some tag, it makes next tag visible. Not done.

This is what I have:

```
$('.group_interests:gt(1)').hide();

$('.group_interests:eq(1)').change( function() {

    $(this) // How to show next element like :eq(+1) or something.

});
```

I don't know how to select `this:eq(+1)`. Then I would simply `.show()` and all would work!

**Outcome:**

```
$('.group_interests:gt(1)').hide();

$('.group_interests:visible').last().change( function() {

    $(this).next().show();

});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at [`jQuery.next()`](http://api.jquery.com/next/).

```
$('.group_interests:eq(1)').change(function() {
    $(this).next().show();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

use next() method to get next element in dom

```
$('.group_interests:gt(1)').hide();

$('.group_interests:eq(1)').change( function() {

    $(this).next().show() // How to show next element like :eq(+1) or something.

});
```

Answer (score 0):

Use $(this).next().show();
This will work.